# How to change app open ad background admob

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, admob

I place the banner ad on the top of the main activity, but when the app switch app open ad shows and violate the AdMob ([policy](https://youtu.be/aZfdufLRZYU?t=161) )

Is that possible to change the background of the app open ad, as you know that by default app open app ad's background is transparent, As a result, when the app open ad shows, the banner ad is also showing in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, After a lot of research, I found the answer,

First, create a theme in style.xml or theme.xml file( make app open ad background black)

```
 <style name="Theme.AppThemeNoActionBar.AdTheme" >
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
</style>
```

and declare the activity on the manifest.xml file, and apply the theme

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppThemeNoActionBar.AdTheme"
        tools:replace="android:theme"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

1: Apply below code in Styles.

```
<style name="myAdTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
</style>
```

2: Apply this code in Manifest file.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:theme="@style/myAdTheme"
        tools:replace="android:theme" />
```

[Click here to preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhoYk.png)

Comment: Your code looks exactly the same as that in the accepted answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it's same. You can use any of them.